# Output from PowerShell to Ansible for Use in Ansible Conditional / Controlling Play Execution

Tags: powershell, ansible

I am using Ansible on Windows hosts by calling PowerShell scripts. It works great, but I have a requirement within my Playbook to only have plays run based on condition (using the Ansible When).

The challenge I am facing is how to output from PowerShell to Ansible. As a use case, lets assume that I have two plays. The first play calls a script to check the PowerShell version number, and the second play should only run if the PowerShell version is 5.0.

How would I, if is it possible, to output from the first play's PowerShell script a variable back to Ansible that can used in the When of the second play to either allow or prevent execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case, you'd probably just want to use the `ansible_powershell_version` fact, eg:

```
- name: do PS5-only thing
  raw: Run-SomePS5Thing
  when: ansible_powershell_version >= 5
```

But in general, to capture stuff in a var and use it later, you can just use the `register:` keyword on the command task in conjunction with filters on the downstream tasks to pluck out the values you need, eg:

```
  # Filters can deal with text too, but since it's Powershell, 
  # let's use structured data- ConvertTo-Json gives us something Ansible
  # can read with the from_json filter
  - raw: Get-NetRoute 0.0.0.0/0 | ConvertTo-Json -depth 1
    register: routeout

  # use from_json to read the stdout from raw and convert to a dictionary 
  # we can pull values from
  - debug: msg="Default gateway is {{ (routeout.stdout | from_json).NextHop }}"

  # or do something conditionally:
  - debug: msg="Default gateway isn't what we expected!"
    when: (routeout.stdout | from_json).NextHop != "192.168.1.1"
```

Comment: I looked in the Windows modules, but did not see ansible_powershell_version. Where is this referneced/are their more like this? Very clear explanation of filters/register

Comment: You must be using a pretty old version of Ansible- it's in at least 2.0+. You'll likely have a much better Windows experience if you get on a new version of Ansible + pywinrm 0.2.0.

Comment: I am using Ansible 2.0+, just didn't see if Ansible_powershell_version is listed in documentation anywhere

Comment: Okay, in looking at the Ansible Docs (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts). it states to use "ansible hostname -m setup" to get the information. Do you know where I can run / how this could be run in a play so I can see all the great facts available to me from a Windows host?

Comment: The setup module == playbook gather_facts, so unless your play has a ```gather_facts: no``` directive, it should already be running first in all your playbooks, so those facts will be implicitly available always.

Comment: Where can I see the output of these? I have set the gather_facts: yes